# Reverse Triangle Inequality with Multiple Terms

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

Given the reverse triangle inequality:

$$ |x+y| \geq ||x|-|y|| $$

Is it valid to extend this to three terms like so:

$$ |x+y+z| \geq ||x|-|y|-|z|| $$

If this is correct could someone point me in the right direction for a proof? Thanks heaps.

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for but this works: $|x+y+z| \geq ||x| - |y+z||$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false, take $x=y=1$ and $z=-2$. On the other hand
$$|x+y+z|=|(x+y)+z| \geq ||x+y|-|z||$$
and by symmetry
$$|x+y+z|\geq \max( ||x+y|-|z||, ||x+z|-|y||, ||y+z|-|x||).$$